# Removing redirect onclick

Tags: javascript

So I want a page to automatically redirect to another page, unless a button is clicked. I was thinking to create an onload redirect and then delete this function onclick of the element.

I have this for now, but I don't know how to stop the function redirect() from activating:

```
 window.onload function redirect() {
  setTimeout("window.location.replace = 'http://redirecturlhere.com';",6000);}

 var popupredirect =  document.querySelector('#popup-pauze');

 document.querySelectorAll('#close-popup').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function() {

 <delete function redirect here>

 ;
 }))
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: Save the id of the timeout and use `clearTImeout()` when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @Pepper you can use the `clearTimout` [Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp):

```
window.onload function redirect() {
   redirectTimeout = setTimeout("window.location.replace = 'http://redirecturlhere.com';",6000);

   var popupredirect =  document.querySelector('#popup-pauze');

   document.querySelectorAll('#close-popup').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function() {
     clearTimeout(redirectTimeout);
   }))
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the very end of line 2. I think OP intended `redirect()` to be the first 2 rows only, in which case he can simply remove the last `}` of your answer (but needs to make sure `redirectTimeout` is declared outside of `redirect()` scope)